# 日本語に違和感: 賛成票のない回答がある質問

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[未回答 > 新着/票/私のタグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)で、右に総数が表示されます。

[image: 賛成票のない回答がある質問]

英語版だとここは "questions with no upvoted answers" で、指している範囲が違います。

英語版の範囲:

```
        | 回答つき | 回答なし |
賛成あり |          |  n/a   |
賛成なし  |   o     |   o    |
```

「賛成票のない回答がある質問」の範囲:

```
        | 回答つき | 回答なし |
賛成あり |          |  n/a   |
賛成なし  |   o     |        |
```

Comment: 現在は、"questions with no upvoted or accepted answers"になっているようですね。さらに日本語訳が悩ましいです。

Answer (score 1):

> 賛成票つきの回答がまだない質問